# Desactivar teclado al hacer focus en un input Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic

Tengo un input que tiene una propiedad focus en el , pero cada vez que borro el valor de este , se me muestra el teclado nativo de android. ¿Existe alguna forma de des habilitar el teclado sin afectar el focus en el input?

```
ionViewDidLoad(){  //Funcion que me permite consultar el producto escaneado
              try{
                setTimeout(() => {
                 this.inputToFocus.setFocus();
               },1000)
                var referenceresultado= this.resultadoref.orderByChild('referencia').equalTo(this.resultado);
                referenceresultado.on('value', itemSnapshot => {
                  this.products = [];
                  itemSnapshot.forEach( itemSnap => {
                    this.products.push(itemSnap.val())
                    return false;
                    this.keyboard.hide();

                  });
                  if (!itemSnapshot.exists()) {
                   let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                    title: 'Producto no encontrado',
                    message: 'Por favor contacte   al administrador',
                    buttons: ['OK'],
                  });
                   alert.present();    
                 }
               });
              }catch(Error){}
            }
```

Front:

```
 <ion-card>  
            <ion-input  type="number"  #inputToFocus [(ngModel)]="resultado" (ngModelChange)="ionViewDidLoad($event.resultado)" ></ion-input>
        </ion-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema que veo es que llamas al método `ionViewDidLoad()` cada vez que hay un cambio en el `input`. Creo que lo correcto seria crear otro método y ponerlo todo menos `this.inputToFocus.setFocus()` que lo pondría en el método `ionViewDidEnter()`.

El método `ionViewDidEnter()` se ejecuta cuando entras a una página, después de cargarla. En cambio el método `ionViewDidLoad()` se ejecuta cuando cargas la página. Si quieres informate mas sobre los [eventos del ciclo de vida](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavController/) de Ionic 3.

Saludos